# Reading session values in jsp

Tags: jsp, session, jstl

I'm making a website with JSP but I'm stucked at the login mechanism.
When someone is logged-in an User-bean is made and send by a session like this (u is filled in before that with a name):

```
session.setAttribute("User", u);
```

The part where I'm stucked is the reading part. Where I want to do something like this:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty user}">
        <c:import url="notlogedin.jsp"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <p><b>Name: </b> ${user.name}</p>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Sorry if it's unclear, I'm really new in Web programming with Java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names are **case sensitive**. You're storing the session attribute with `"User"` (capital U) and reading it as `user` (no capitals at all). Choose one word only.

Comment: you have to be kidding me! I'm looking for an answer almost for 2 hours now, THANK YOU!

Comment: You're welcome. And yeah, this kind of things happens :P